# Is spacetime multilayerd?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime

They say celestial objects like Earth make a curve on spacetime due to their heavy mass.
Well what about any object just above Earth? They do poses mass then they make a curve in spacetime.
So, isn't Earth passing through the Spacetime of that object? Which means Spacetime is being holed by Earth.

So is Spacetime multilayered and is local for an object?
But it can't be for the cause of gravity will invalidated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a single spacetime which is curved by all objects with either mass, energy, or both. The Earth curves space, so do cups and chairs, and light itself. The curvature of spacetime is very complicated as a result. However, things with less mass cause spacetime to curve less, and hence for any practical application, the curvature caused by cups and chairs will be negligible compared to what the Earth is doing, and hence ignored.

The precise relationship between the curvature of spacetime and mass/energy is given by the Einstein field equations.